# Div floating on top of another div incorrectly

Tags: html, css

The idea is to have view like this:

```
Hello                           World 
I should be below the hello world line.
```

The html/css fragment:

```
<div>
    <div style="display:block;">
        <span style="float: left;">
           <label style="width:30%;">Hello</label>
        </span>
        <span style="float: right;">
             <label style="width:70%;text-align:right;">World</label>
        </span>        
    </div>
   <div>
            <label>I should be below the Hello World line.</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pga06pss/

The last div containing: 'I should be below hello world line' - actually ends up in top line immediately after hello, i want it to appear below that.

Comment: Because you haven't contained/cleared the floats - https://jsfiddle.net/pga06pss/

Comment: And why exactly is the question down-voted?

Comment: The reasons for downvoting are "lack of research effort" , "unclear" and "not useful". At a guess, I'd assume the first. This is a very common issue that *probably* could have been resolved with a simple Google or SO Search. Anyway, that's my guess.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for your inputs - but those who do not come from CSS background - its a very valid question. Plain intellectual arrogance i guess :)

Comment: Got through the tutorial at http://learnlayout.com/. It should help you understand element positioning behavior better.

Answer (score 1):

> If the element can fit horizontally in the space next to another
>   element which is floated, it will. Unless you apply clear to that
>   element in the same direction as the float. Then the element will move
>   down below the floated element.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clear/

```html
<div>
  <div style="display:block">
    <span style="float: left;">
               <label style="width:30%;">Hello</label>
            </span>
    <span style="float: right;">
                 <label style="width:70%;text-align:right;">World</label>
            </span> 
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both">
    Why am I not on a separate line
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jasper I don't know. but hope my answer helped you understand how floating works :)

Answer (score 1):

The parent is being collapsed by it's floated children. The best way of combatting this is to use a clearfix:

```css
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
    <div>
        <div style="display:block;" class="cf">
            <span style="float: left;">
               <label style="width:30%;">Hello</label>
            </span>
            <span style="float: right;">
                 <label style="width:70%;text-align:right;">World</label>
            </span>        
        </div>
       <div>
                Why am I not on a separate line
       </div>
    </div>
```

You'll notice now that the parent has got it's height back whereas in your example, it is completely collapsed (0px height)!

Clearfix source: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

More info on floats: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/